# Why my function with negative numbers is not working

Tags: javascript

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  let maxOfEach = [];
  for (let i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i ++){
          let tempx = [i][0];
      for (let j = 1 ; j < arr[i].length ; j++){
          if (arr[i][j] > tempx){
            tempx = arr[i][j]
          }
      }
      maxOfEach.push(tempx);
  }
  // You can do this!
  return maxOfEach;
}
let x= 
largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [-2222, -22, -222, -2222], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
console.log(x);
```

Here is the code the problem is about negative numbers
when I am putting negative numbers in an array then array works not properly and shows me 1 instead of -22 
But, when I am making the same thing with positive numbers all, is ok
please help me to find the mistake in the code.

Comment: `let tempx = [i][0];` this looks like someone put `let tempx = i;` into an obfuscator. Did you maybe intend `let tempx = arr[i][0];`? It also looks, like it explains your bug.

Comment: oh thank you  , yes you are right

Answer (score -1):

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  let maxOfEach = [];
  for (let i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i ++){
          let tempx = arr[i][0];
      for (let j = 1 ; j < arr[i].length ; j++){
          if (arr[i][j] > tempx){
            tempx = arr[i][j]
          }
      }
      maxOfEach.push(tempx);
  }
  // You can do this!
  return maxOfEach;
}
let x= 
largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [-2222, -22, -222, -2222], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
console.log(x);
```

let tempx = arr[i][0];  the problem was this ,before i had let tempx = [i][0];

Comment: What is this? The solution for your own question?
If yes, please, [edit] it and tell why your answer solves your question